# How magnetorquers desaturate reaction wheel?

Tags: reaction-wheel, magnetorquer

I am looking for a solution to solve problem of reaction wheel saturation. I am going to use magnetorquers as actuator for desaturation. Any one who can guide me in this respect?

Comment: Magnetorquers do generate real torque and so can in principle be used for some reaction wheel desaturation. Do you have any particular reaction wheel in mind? Satellite size? If you are thinking along the lines of cubesats a search of perhaps "cubesat COTS magnetorquer" and "cubesat COTS reaction wheel" will give you some standard parts. You can get an idea of the maximum torque a magnetotorquer can produce, and then get an idea how many hours, days or even weeks it would take to desaturate a reaction wheel at saturation.

Comment: It looks like your question was closed as duplicate. If you can rewrite your question to differentiate it from the previous answers, there is a re-open process if you are interested.